# Udev rule file for modem not working

Tags: udev, modem, mobile

I am using a modem for sending SMS, which has 16 (`ttyUSB0` to `ttyUSB15`) ports. I want to make `udev` rule to give device name `AMPM` and ports should be named `Port1`, `Port2`,...`Port16`.

Check out this output of `lsusb` and `udevadm` command on port `ttyUSB0`.

```
kk@kk:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd
Bus 001 Device 015: ID 0409:005a NEC Corp. HighSpeed Hub
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0403:6011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:2003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 0403:6011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 0403:6011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 0403:6011 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
kk@kk:~$

kk@kk:~$ udevadm info -q all -n /dev/ttyUSB0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-3/1-3.1/1-3.1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
N: ttyUSB0
S: serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_Quad_RS232-HS-if00-port0
S: serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3.1:1.0-port0
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-FTDI_Quad_RS232-HS-if00-port0 /dev/serial/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3.1:1.0-port0
E: DEVNAME=/dev/ttyUSB0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.7/usb1/1-3/1-3.1/1-3.1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL=Quad_RS232-HS
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Quad\x20RS232-HS
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=FT4232H Quad HS USB-UART/FIFO IC
E: ID_MODEL_ID=6011
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.7-usb-0:3.1:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_7-usb-0_3_1_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0800
E: ID_SERIAL=FTDI_Quad_RS232-HS
E: ID_TYPE=generic
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=ftdi_sio
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:ffffff:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=FTDI
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=FTDI
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0403
E: MAJOR=188
E: MINOR=0
E: SUBSYSTEM=tty
E: UDEV_LOG=3
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=7668235100
```

I am getting fail in following `udev` rule.

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-15]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{product}=="6011", NAME=="AMPM" , SYMLINK=="AMPM", GROUP="tty", MODE="0660"
```

Comment: seems devices are being created properly. what's output of `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB*` ?

Comment: Meet me on chat, I can't paste here as I finished all capacity.

Comment: didn't find you on chat. have to leave for work. check in later.

Comment: @K.KPatel I'm confused as to how you plan to symlink 16 different devices to one file... But anyway, I think you want `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"` At least guessing from one of the default rules.

Comment: @K.KPatel Also, the key debugging tool is `udevadm`. E.g., `udevadm info --query=all --name /dev/ttyUSB0` will help you. Or `--attribute-walk`.

Comment: @derobert You are right But how to solve this. I think SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial" is for serial cables. I used usb only.Finally I want to give name to particular port like AMPM1,AMPM2...,to ports.and I already used udevadm. but due to any mistake in configuration I am going to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait — I see it. Two things:

1. You used `ATTRS{product}=="6011"` when you meant `ATTRS{idProduct}=="6011"`. That missing `id` will break it. Copy-and-paste from `udevadm info --attribute-walk` to prevent typos like this.
2. Your pattern is wrong; it should be `KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*"`. It's a (very limited) regular expression, so `[0-15]*` means "any of the characters 0–1 or 5, repeated any number of times".

Also, you probably want to use `SYMLINK+=` instead of `SYMLINK==` to preserve the other links. You're correct that it needs to be `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"` to match on product/vendor.

In order to number your AMPM devices, you need to give `udev` the number. Unfortunately, this is part of the `usb-serial` device, not the `usb` one. So you can't just use `%s{port_number}`/`$attr{port_number}`. Instead, borrow a trick from `60-persistent-serial.rules` in newer `udev` versions, and do something like this:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial", ENV{.LOCAL_PORT_NUM}="$attr{port_number}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6011", SYMLINK+="AMPM$env{.LOCAL_PORT_NUM}"
```

On older `udev`, you may have to use `%E{…}` instead of `$env{…}`.

Or, alternatively, if your `udev` is new enough, just use `/dev/serial/by-id`:

```
$ ls -l /dev/serial/by-id/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Jan  4 06:02 usb-067b_2303-if00-port0 -> ../../ttyUSB0
```

You should see your vendor/product code there, and all your ports.

Answer (score 3):

Had similar needs; to map many FTDI usb-serial devices to unique names, so that scripts can refer them uniquely.

On an Ubuntu 13.04, after some tinkering, the following worked for me.

Hopefully may be of help:

```
#######################################################################################################################################
# Creating unique symbolic links to usb-serial devices based on their "serial" number and other such as "bInterfaceNumber" attributes.
# Use udevadm [e.g. udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n ttyUSB0)] to find the subsystems that match and their attributes.
#######################################################################################################################################
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:1d.0", ENV{.LOCAL_serial}="$attr{serial}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{.LOCAL_ifNum}="$attr{bInterfaceNumber}"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010", ENV{.LOCAL_serial}=="0000:00:1d.0", ENV{.LOCAL_ifNum}=="00",  SYMLINK+="ttyPapilioJTAG",  MODE="0660"
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6010", ENV{.LOCAL_serial}=="0000:00:1d.0", ENV{.LOCAL_ifNum}=="01",  SYMLINK+="ttyPapilioConsole",  MODE="0660"
```