# Udev rule to match multiple node USB device

Tags: linux, devices, udev

I have a 3G/GPS device that creates 5 tty nodes, although it's only one physical USB connection. Basically, a multi port usb-serial adapter.

I'm trying to create some `udev` rules to make sure those nodes always have the same name, or at least a symlink to them.

I can indeed find the device at `/sys/devices/platform/pxa27x-ohci/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/`. Inside are `1-2.2:1.0/` to `1-2.2:1.4/`, for the 5 nodes it creates.

I can also find it at `/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2.2` .

The udev info for the device is as follows:

```
udevadm info -a -p /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-2.2/1-2.2\:1.0
looking at device '/bus/usb/devices/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.0':
KERNEL=="1-2.2:1.0"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb"
DRIVER=="option"
ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
ATTR{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
ATTR{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
ATTR{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
ATTR{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
ATTR{modalias}=="usb:v12D1p1506d0000dc00dsc00dp00icFFisc01ip01"
ATTR{supports_autosuspend}=="0"
```

From this point on, all the nodes have the same info. And the only thing varying between nodes is the bInterfaceNumber property, and the device path. So, I thought of writing a rule by dev path.

Now, for some reason, the following rule gets matched by all those nodes.

```
ACTION=="add", DEV="/devices/platform/pxa27x-ohci/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.0" SYMLINK+="huawey0"
```

So basically, `huawey0` points to the last node enumerated. The device created nodes from ttyUSB2 to 6, and this link points to USB6.

So, I tried by kernel node:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="1-2.2:1.0" SYMLINK+="huawey0"
```

Now, nothing appears on /dev.

After this, I tried using the bInterfaceNumber to separate them. I used the following rule

```
ACTION=="add", DEV="/devices/platform/pxa27x-ohci/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.[0-4]" ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}=="00" SYMLINK+="huawey0"
```

And still, nothing happens. I even tried a trimmed down version of the rule..

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}=="00" SYMLINK+="huawey0"
```

And still nothing happens. Why is it not matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your rules all have syntax errors in them:

1. `=` is for assignment `==` is for comparison, so you were not actually looking at what `DEV` equaled, you were assigning it.
2. You need `,` between all the statements, there were none before `SYMLINK+=`.

### Fist Rule

```
ACTION=="add", DEV=="/devices/platform/pxa27x-ohci/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.0", SYMLINK+="huawey0"
```

### Second Rule

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="1-2.2:1.0", SYMLINK+="huawey0"
```

### Third Rule

```
ACTION=="add", DEV=="/devices/platform/pxa27x-ohci/usb1/1-2/1-2.2/1-2.2:1.[0-4]", ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", SYMLINK+="huawey0"
```

### Fourth Rule

```
ACTION=="add", ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}=="00", SYMLINK+="huawey0"
```

All these rules should do what you want now (I would use the first one personally).

Answer (score 6):

Although this post was asked three years ago, and this might not address the answer, I still want to share my successful experience here for the future reference.

According to Jens Reimann's [Identify GSM modem devices using udev](https://dentrassi.de/2014/11/03/identify-gsm-modem-devices-using-udev/), "the device attribute “bInterfaceNumber” is not on the tty device, but on the usb device in the parent hierarchy", so I created two rules for my FTDI usb-to-4-port-serial adapter:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{.LOCAL_ifNum}="$attr{bInterfaceNumber}"

SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6011", SYMLINK+="ttyUSB_FTDI_4_PORT_%E{.LOCAL_ifNum}"
```

> This stores the attribute “bInterfaceNumber” into the environment variable “.LOCAL_ifNum” (the prefixed dot is a notation for temporary or hidden variables). In the second rule the same variable is pulled on using the “%E” syntax. Newer udev versions also support “$env” instead of “%E”.
>   (by Jens Reimann)

where `ttyUSB_FTDI_4_PORT_` is the symlink name. 
These two rules will create symlinks as `ttyUSB_FTDI_4_PORT_00`, `ttyUSB_FTDI_4_PORT_01`, `ttyUSB_FTDI_4_PORT_02`, `ttyUSB_FTDI_4_PORT_03`. 
You can add `ATTRS{serial}` attribute to constrain the enumeration further.

Jens Reimann also acknowlegfed the contribution of [Ketan Patel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/28793/ketan-patel)'s U&L question, [Udev rule file for modem not working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60154/udev-rule-file-for-modem-not-working), with [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60154/80216#60272) by [derobert](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/977/derobert).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alex's comments, there is another issue.  It seems `ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}` doesn't work for some reason.  To quote [the answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176829/1048959), you should use something along the lines of

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ACTION=="add", \
    ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="067b", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}="2303", \
    ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM}=="00", SYMLINK+="test_USB0"
```