# udev rule not working when adding bInterfaceNumber

Tags: linux, usb, udev

This is my udev rule

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4", ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea71", ATTRS{serial}=="0", ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00",RUN+="/home/jamal/test.sh"
```

The script is not running when I add bInterfaceNumber comparison, when i remove it works..

Here is the output of udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="cp210x"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3/2-2.3:1.0':
    KERNELS=="2-2.3:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="cp2108"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="02"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    **ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"**
    ATTRS{interface}=="CP2108 Interface 0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2/2-2.3':
    KERNELS=="2-2.3"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2.3"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="10c4"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 4"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="57"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0004"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="213"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Silicon Labs"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="ea71"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{product}=="CP2108 Quad USB to UART Bridge Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2/2-2':
    KERNELS=="2-2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="2"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="0e0f"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="3"
    ATTRS{configuration}=="VMware Virtual USB Hub"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="7"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0100"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="1215"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="VMware Virtual USB Hub"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0/usb2':
    KERNELS=="usb2"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="2"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0404"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:02:00.0"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="32"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.4.0-31-generic uhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{product}=="UHCI Host Controller"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:00.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:02:00.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="uhci_hcd"
    ATTRS{irq}=="18"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x15ad"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0300"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="0000000f"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x0774"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x15ad"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x1976"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:11.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS==""
    ATTRS{irq}=="0"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x15ad"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x060401"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="0000000f"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x0790"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x15ad"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x0790"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

You can observe bInterfaceNumber is "00" . Can you please tell me what mistake I am doing..

Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: check out this [second answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373211/119298). You need a 2 step rule, passing info through the ENVironment.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the other attributes are at the device level (idVendor, idProduct, serial) while bInterfaceNumber is at the interface level. So there is no udev entry that matches all conditions at once.

Comment: How can we use both in a single use rule